# unexpected output from print function

Tags: c++

I feel pretty dumb having to ask for help with this but I'm pulling my hair out.

I have this printSong() function that prints song info from a song database.

```
void Song::printSong(int &i)                                           
{   
    cout << right << i+1 <<") "<< songName << '\t' << artist << '\t'<< internal 
         << setfill('0') << setw(2) << min << ":" << internal << setfill('0') 
         << setw(2) << sec << '\t' << album << endl;
}
```

and I call it from this function:

```
void SongList::displayAll(int &numSongs, int &i)
{
    clearScreen();

    cout << "Index" << '\t' <<  "Song "<< '\t' <<  '\t' 
         << "Artist " <<'\t' << '\t'<< "Time" << '\t' << "Album" << endl;
    cout << "******************************************************************************"<< endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        list[i].printSong(i);
    }
    cout << "numSongs = " << numSongs << endl;
    cout << "Press enter to return to the menu: ";
}
```

When this prints, it goes to a new line after printing the index number. 
For example, it should look like this:

```
1) House of Cards     Radiohead    05:28     In Rainbows
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
1 
) House of Cards    Radiohead     05:28      In Rainbows
```

I cannot figure out why it's doing this.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Make a [mcve]. You refer to a `printSong()` function. Show that function and the function that calls it. What output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: I'm confused.  I show both of those functions above.  And I have given an example of what the output should be versus what it actually is.

Comment: Certainly stepping through your program line by line with your debugger would reveal when the newline is inserted.

Comment: What is `right` in your `printsong`?

Comment: That's just to format it to the right. I was having this problem before I added that, though.

Comment: Tried it, but nothing changed.  Looks like it's time for me to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Cortex Why should `std::right` make any difference here?

Comment: Preparing a minimal complete example isn't just for our convenience; in the process, you'll probably find the bug, because you'll be clearing away the thicket where a bug can hide. It's a vital coding skill, even when you don't have access to a forum like this.

Comment: @newGirl What is there to be confused about? When I wrote the comment the function's signature was non-existant. It was cigen that edited it in. As the person asking a question, be prepared to do the grund work when it comes to presenting the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: @cigien he did not specify that he was using std::right. That being said, 'std::cout << i+1 <<") ";'  does not create a new line. Therefor the issue would have to be with the variable that was unspecifed.

Comment: @cigien evidently I though right was a variable, which is why you dont use using namespace std..

Comment: @Cortex That's certainly true, `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Comment: Everyting had been solved much quicker had there been a [mcve].

Comment: I run your code and cannot reproduce the issue. It works as required - without breaking line.